# ceph orch host add host issues (env: centos8, ceph:12.2.5)

Tags: ceph, centos8

information:
hostnames:
cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
172.16.49.41 ceph-gw-one
172.16.49.42 ceph-gw-two

shell: ceph orch host add 172.16.49.42

Error EINVAL: New host 172.16.49.42 (172.16.49.42) failed check: ['INFO:cephadm:podman|docker (/bin/docker) is present', 'INFO:cephadm:systemctl is present', 'INFO:cephadm:lvcreate is present', 'INFO:cephadm:Unit chronyd.service is enabled and running', 'INFO:cephadm:Hostname "172.16.49.42" matches what is expected.', 'ERROR: hostname "ceph-gw-two" does not match expected hostname "172.16.49.42"']

shell: orch host add ceph-gw-two

Error EINVAL: Failed to connect to ceph-gw-two (ceph-gw-two).
Check that the host is reachable and accepts connections using the cephadm SSH key

you may want to run:

> ceph cephadm get-ssh-config > ssh_config
> ceph config-key get mgr/cephadm/ssh_identity_key > key
> ssh -F ssh_config -i key root@ceph-gw-two

i have checked that wether by ip or hostname, ssh login success;

Answer (score 0):

i read the adm source scripts：

```
 out, err, code = self._run_cephadm(spec.hostname, cephadmNoImage, 'check-host',
                                       ['--expect-hostname', spec.hostname],
                                       addr=spec.addr,
                                       error_ok=True, no_fsid=True)
    if code:
        raise OrchestratorError('New host %s (%s) failed check: %s' % (
            spec.hostname, spec.addr, err))
```

so ,i change the cmd to:

ceph orch host add ceph-gw-two 172.16.49.42;

done, it works well;